# PostgreSQL & PHP connection problem

Tags: php, postgresql

Folowing [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/528426/postgresql-connection-problems) by CountZero, apparently i'm facing same problem here.
When my site trying to open connection with the database, **SOMETIME** (Not *Always*) i get following error:

> Warning: pg_connect()
>   [function.pg-connect]: Unable to
>   connect to PostgreSQL server: server
>   closed the connection unexpectedly
>   This probably means the server
>   terminated abnormally before or while
>   processing the request. in
>   E:\htdocs\trial_pg\client_1a.php on
>   line 3

Here is my client1a.php script:

```
<?php
  $connString = 'dbname=movies user=xxxxxx password=xxxxxx';
  $connHandler = pg_connect($connString);
  echo 'Connected to '.pg_dbname($connHandler);
?>
```

This happens often, especially when I refresh the page (F5) repeatedly to test the connection. I'm new with postgresql, and this is the developing environment of my site:

**OS:** Windows 7 Professional

**Web Server:** Apache/2.2.14 (Win32) DAV/2 mod_ssl/2.2.14 OpenSSL/0.9.8l mod_autoindex_color mod_apreq2-20090110/2.7.1 mod_perl/2.0.4 Perl/v5.10.1

**PHP:** 5.3.1

**PostgreSQL:** 8.4.3

Are there any configuration i miss?
Any hints?

Thanks!

Comment: +1 for a very neatly presented question

Comment: The script name it is looking for has an '_' (underscore). client_1a.php

Comment: Could it be that php doesn't immediately close the connection on script end? I see no explicit `pg_close()` in your code. Look at the postgres logs for any possible details of this.

Comment: PHP should run pg_close automatically at script end. How many times are you trying to open the connection (per script run)? Once? Twice? More? Look for max_connections here http://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.4/static/runtime-config-connection.html then check your config, if you're at default of 100 that should be plenty, and sounds like it's something with the server itself. If you're opening 20+ connections on each script run (instead of reusing them) Then that could be the problem.

Comment: @AJ: Hmm, it should be client_1a.php. Thanks for the correction :)

Comment: @Fanis: From this script, i plan to develop a connection db script to be included on every page that need a db connection (i think it will make my documentation easier). It usually works well with MySQL (TT-TT)

Comment: @Viper_Sb: I left the configuration to default. And, if you look at my simple script, i believe i only create one connection handler ;) I've tried to put pg_close at the end of script, but still, it didn't solve the problem :(

Answer (score 4):

Okay, so here is the answer of my question ;)

## JUST RESTART THE POSTGRESQL SERVICE :)

I hope if everyone encountered the same problem, you know what you should do to solve it :D

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes this kind of problems are caused by over-enthusiastic antivirus software, if it monitors TCP connections. Do you have any antivirus running there?

Comment: I don't think so. I've been using Eset Smart Security for over 2 yrs and it's working fine even for Oracle. I think the problems is the postgresql itself ;)